# sudo chmod 755 [file]: operation not permitted!

Tags: 18.04, sudo, chmod

I wanted change the permission of a file that I own previously, so I typed:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 [file]
[sudo] password for rakinar2:
sudo: chmod: Operation not permitted
```

How do I fix this issue? I'm using ubuntu bionic.

EDIT [11 Jul 2021]:
I run `lsattr [file]` and it says `Permission denied while trying to stat [file]`

Comment: Operation not permitted means you cannot change it. Reason might be that the file system is read only. If it normally should not be read only, then include information about it in your question. Is it a file on your root partition? Is it a file in your home folder? If not, what is the file system? The command `lsblk -ls -fs` provided info on your file systems, including the mount point.

Comment: @vanadium I was at `/home/rakinar2` and the partition was writable.

Comment: Use "edit" to add any information that could be relevant to solve the problem to your question. Comments may disappear anytime. Normally, when a partition is writable, root can change permissions of a file, so something else is going on here.

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Comment: `lsattr "your file"` please show it.